# How to output css to kestrel in OS X using Visual Studio Code

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a website using kestrel on OS X using Visual Studio Code and am able to get the MVC 6 bits working with Entity Framework 7 (InMemory), but am unable to wrap my head around the config and build process using grunt, bower, gulp, etc. The webpage source shows that the href is as expected, but there is no content when inspecting the file in chrome developer tools.

Is there a sample where css in wwwroot/css/site.css is included in the output website?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these samples: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/samples. "MvcSample.Web" contains *.css files in the wwwroot.